# Unable to enter filter text in Kendo grid if using column menu

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have used kendo MVC grid in my project and added column menu functionality to it. Whenever I try to filter records using column menu then filter box is automatically closed if i do not change filter type i.e. (Is Equal To, Contains, etc).

Issue is also present in kendo official website. Follow the link 
[Kendo Grid Column Menu](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/column-menu)

In the link perform following operation to regenerate issue:

1. Click column menu for Order ID
2. Mouse over to Filter
3. Try to focus textbox in filter box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next official release(R1 2017), which should be soon as the release webinar is scheduled for Jan 24.

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/2584

Or, you could use the latest internal build(v2016.3.1306).

Comment: Thanks for the great help!!